# Angular 2 does not render custom tags in the template HTML

Tags: angular, custom-tag

I am having a weird behaviour with Angular 2.
Actually, my application is pretty straightforward. It has a main page component called `kys-app`. In that, I am specifying the template HTML as `kys-app.html`. The HTML is also very simple. It has four parts: header, sidemenu, footer and the main contents. Header, footer and sidemenu have their own template HTMLs which are defined in their own component files. (`header.ts`, `footer.ts` and `sidemenu.ts`). 
The main content is expected to be displayed in router-outlet.
Here is `kys-app.ts` :

```
            import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable, Inject, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
            import { Router, RouterModule }         from '@angular/router';
            import { FormsModule }                  from '@angular/forms';
            import { HttpModule, XHRBackend }       from '@angular/http';

            //import { HeaderComp }      from '../../components/app/header';
            import { FooterComp }        from '../../components/app/footer';
            //import { SideMenuComp }    from '../../components/app/side-menu';
            //import { AuthGuard }       from '/app/services/auth-guard';

            @Component({
                imports: [ HttpModule, RouterModule ],
                selector: 'kys-app',
                templateUrl: '/app/components/app/kys-app.html',
                directives: [ FooterComp ], 
                schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
               // providers: [ {provide: Router, useClass: RouterModule} ]
            })

            export class KYSAppComp {

                 constructor() {
                     console.log(' %% KYSAppComp %%');

                 }
            }
```

And my `kys-app.html` content is as follows:

```
            <!-- Main Content -->
                <section class="content-wrap">
                    <div class="card-panel">

                  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

                <!--   Footer -->
                <kys-footer></kys-footer>
                    </div>

                </section>
                <!-- /Main Content -->
```

Note: In order to simplify it, temporarily I removed header and sidemenu components. 
So, when I access the main page, I expect to see the main content in router-outlet section and below it the footer contents.

What I am seeing is: Although the main contents (the contents of the component that I am accessing through the Router path (e.g: `/#/login` )) are correctly being displayed but other sections of `kys-app` are not being displayed (e.g footer contents). In other words Angular 2 does not render the custom tags defined in `kys-app` (e.g.: `<kys-footer>` ).

Could anyone have a look at the codes above and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Previously when I had this kind of problem, adding schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] had solved the issue. But this time it did not make any difference. In addition, I also tried using declarations: [ FooterComp ] instead of directives, it did not work either.

Comment: And here is my footer.ts , in case you may want to see it as well :     
                   import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
     selector: 'kys-footer',
     templateUrl: '/app/components/app/footer.html',
     schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    export class FooterComp {

      constructor(  ) { 
         console.log('%% FooterComp %%');
      
       }
     }

Answer (score 3):

`imports: []` needs to go to `@NgModule()`, it's invalid in `@Component()`
same with `directives: [ FooterComp ],`, which should be

```ts
 @NgModule({ 
   imports: [ HttpModule, RouterModule ],
   declarations: [ FooterComp ],
```

You seem to somehow mix pre 2.0.0 final with post 2.0.0 final style.
Please check the docs at angular.io for more details how to create components and modules.

Comment: Thanks Günter, that was it. It solved my problem.  Sometimes, one needs a look from a different perspective :)   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: In order to clarify the solution let me explain how it was solved: As Günter pointed out, I removed imports and directives from kys-app Component. the app.module.ts already had the imports, and I added FooterComp in the declarations section of the app.module.ts and it worked.